# Kaplan Meier - Can I use to assess recovery of function, not just loss?

Tags: survival, kaplan-meier

In my experience and readings, Kaplan-Meier has always been used to calculate differential survival between a certain number of groups. However, I'm looking to assess how time to recovery from a certain event as measured by activity levels. At time zero, everyone is essentially "dead" (non-mobile), and with time they regain mobility. 
seems like a "negative" Kaplan-Meier, is that possible? Or should I be looking at a different modeling strategy?

Comment: so if you simply choose the right definitions ('death' in this case is 'of immobility') ... it would seem to be very sensible; any change of state works really, it doesn't have to be death. The only thing that worries me is that while people don't generally recover from death after a few months (once you have entered the state for more than a few minutes, you remain there) ... but people can potentially become non-mobile again. If that can't/won't happen in your circumstances, there should be no problem; if it can, then you might look at models where people can move between states over time.

Comment: This is more about how you define an "event." It's called "survival" but the event does not have to be lacking ability to survive. Turning the idea around, you can use 1 to represent "revival."

Comment: @Glen_b, thats exactly my problem. during recovery you can certainly move back and forth between states. I'm envisioning something like this: [link](http://imgur.com/1KkvScI) but with the ability to have increasing/decreasing mobility, and the "event" being reaching your baseline

Comment: There are already models for sickness and disability of varying levels of sophistication, often based on Markov chains (a small number of states, often continuous time), or related to them. It's quite possible to have several different levels of mobility. [e.g.](http://www.google.com/search?q=markov+chain+sickness|disability+models)